# Python: Rewrite a pretty XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, minidom

I've got a XML file which looks like this:

```
<Main>

    <Stuff author="Jojo" name="Thing 1">
        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />
        <Attr name="description" value="Long description" />
        <Attr name="version" value="1.0.0" />
        <Attr name="software" value="Misrocoft Ociffe" />
        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />
        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />
        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />
    </Stuff>

    <Stuff author="Toto" name="Thing 2">
        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />
        <Attr name="description" value="Long description"/>
        <Attr name="version" value="4.3.9" />
        <Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop" />
        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />
        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />
        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />
    </Stuff>

</Main>
```

I'm updating it and then rewriting it but the problem is that if I rewriting it with `prettyxml` I've got new spaces between the old lines like this:

```
<Main>


    <Stuff author="Jojo" name="Thing 1">


        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />


        <Attr name="description" value="Long description" />


        <Attr name="version" value="1.0.0" />


        <Attr name="software" value="Misrocoft Ociffe" />


        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />


        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />


        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />


    </Stuff>

    <Stuff author="Toto" name="Thing 2">


        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />


        <Attr name="description" value="Long description"/>


        <Attr name="version" value="4.3.9" />


        <Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop" />


        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />


        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />


        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />


    </Stuff>

    <Stuff author="Titi" name="New thing">
        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />
        <Attr name="description" value="Long description"/>
        <Attr name="version" value="4.3.9" />
        <Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop" />
        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />
        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />
        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />
    </Stuff>

</Main>
```

And if I rewrite it `toxml` I've got no indentations or spaces at all like this:

```
<Main>

    <Stuff author="Jojo" name="Thing 1">
        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />
        <Attr name="description" value="Long description" />
        <Attr name="version" value="1.0.0" />
        <Attr name="software" value="Misrocoft Ociffe" />
        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />
        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />
        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />
    </Stuff>

    <Stuff author="Toto" name="Thing 2">
        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />
        <Attr name="description" value="Long description"/>
        <Attr name="version" value="4.3.9" />
        <Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop" />
        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />
        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />
        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />
    </Stuff>

<Stuff author="Titi" name="New thing"><Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" /><Attr name="description" value="Long description"/><Attr name="version" value="4.3.9" /><Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop" /><Attr name="language" value="Python" /><Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" /><Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" /></Stuff></Main>
```

Is there a way to output a new pretty XML which will not modify the existing format of the file?
I was thinking of changing the XML to a one-line string and then re-writing it in prettyxml but I don't know how to do it or if it is possible (I'm using `etree` and `minidom` for info).

---

### Update (answer):

Here is the code I finally made, note that my `rootXml` is from ElementTree.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def writeXml(rootXml, xmlFile):

    roughString = ET.tostring(rootXml, 'utf-8')
    oneLineString = ''.join([s.strip() for s in roughString.splitlines()])

    minidomXml = minidom.parseString(oneLineString)
    rootMinidom = minidomXml.firstChild

    prettyXmlString = rootMinidom.toprettyxml()
    prettyXml = ET.fromstring(prettyXmlString)

    with open(xmlFile, "w") as f:
        f.write (ET.tostring(prettyXml))
```

Will return the following xml:

```
<Main>
    <Stuff author="Jojo" name="Thing 1">
        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />
        <Attr name="description" value="Long description" />
        <Attr name="version" value="1.0.0" />
        <Attr name="software" value="Misrocoft Ociffe" />
        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />
        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />
        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />
    </Stuff>
    <Stuff author="Toto" name="Thing 2">
        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />
        <Attr name="description" value="Long description"/>
        <Attr name="version" value="4.3.9" />
        <Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop" />
        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />
        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />
        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />
    </Stuff>
    <Stuff author="Titi" name="New thing">
        <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" />
        <Attr name="description" value="Long description"/>
        <Attr name="version" value="4.3.9" />
        <Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop" />
        <Attr name="language" value="Python" />
        <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" />
        <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" />
    </Stuff>
</Main>
```

Comment: you are wasting your time. White spaces between tags aren't important. Just ignore them

Comment: It's for readability mainly. ^^

Comment: @e4c5 So then why do pretty XML at all? just put it all into a file without whitespaces between tags. That'll make it easy to ready by a human...

Comment: @busfault Oh I am sorry I didn't realize that there were people who actually read xml when others read comics

Comment: @e4c5 I guess you have never had the pleasure of trying to debug someone else's messed up XML. Your code must be wonderfully easy to debug.

Comment: @busfault use an XML viewer for that. For them it doesn't matter whether you have no space or a 100 spaces. And they give you nice syntax hightlighting too.

Comment: @busfault I am sorry if it was interpreted as rude but that was just stating the facts.

Comment: @UKDP Sorry for hijacking your post. Anyway. can you post some of your code that you are doing the writing with?

Comment: Ok, I actually found a way to do it which seems fast and neat, I'd like to answer my own question but can't find where is it... If someone can tell me, or I'll just update my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way to fix `minidom`'s `toprettyxml()` as far as I can find *. One of the easiest way is probably using `BeautifulSoup`'s `prettify()`. For example, your single-line `Stuff` element is properly separated into new-lines with indentations by `prettify()` :

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> raw = '''<Stuff author="Titi" name="New thing"><Attr name="annotation" value="Short description" /><Attr name="description" value="Long description"/><Attr name="version" value="4.3.9" /><Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop" /><Attr name="language" value="Python" /><Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext" /><Attr name="command" value="doSomething()" /></Stuff>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, "xml")
>>> print soup.prettify()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stuff author="Titi" name="New thing">
 <Attr name="annotation" value="Short description"/>
 <Attr name="description" value="Long description"/>
 <Attr name="version" value="4.3.9"/>
 <Attr name="software" value="Tophoshop"/>
 <Attr name="language" value="Python"/>
 <Attr name="path" value="/here/there/aroundHere/somewhere/file.ext"/>
 <Attr name="command" value="doSomething()"/>
</Stuff>
```

*) References :

- [problem with the new lines when I use toprettyxml()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662351/problem-with-the-new-lines-when-i-use-toprettyxml)
- [Empty lines while using minidom.toprettyxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479656/empty-lines-while-using-minidom-toprettyxml)
- [Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

Comment: Your first link seems a plain duplicate to me...